# result of php input is 1 instead of XML data

Tags: php, xml, curl, domdocument

I'm reading an XML data from a PHP input and i'm receving the number 1 instead of the XML data.

the PHP code for reading the XML Data from PHP input:

```
            $xmlStr="";
            $file=fopen('php://input','r');
            while ($line=fgets($file) !== false) {
              $xmlStr .= $line;
            }
            fclose($file);
```

the PHP code for sending the XML:

```
public static function xmlPost($url,$xml) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); // set url to post to
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); // set url to post to
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // return into a variable
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: text/xml"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40); // times out after 4s
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml); // add POST fields
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    $result=curl_exec ($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

no matter what XML i'm sending, the receiving end is getting the number 1 instead
of the XML data. any ideas?

any information regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated.

## update

the following code works:

```
$xmlStr = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

but why my code doesn't ?
why my code returns 1 instead of the actual xml ?

Comment: Could you try `$xmlStr = file_get_contents('php://input');`

Comment: with file_get_contents i'm getting the xml.. i'm trying to find out what's wrong with this code.. i'm trying to work with this way (i'm working with a client that gets 1 with my code and i'm trying to find out why.. i'll change to !==)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though I'd suggest using [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), too, to answer your question:
Because of [operator precedence](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) the line

```
while ($line=fgets($file) !== false)
```

doesn't work the way you want it to. The result of the comparison `fgets($file) !== false` is assigned to $line. When you append it to $xmlStr the boolean value is cast to string. Since the condition of the while loop is that $line is true `(string)$line` will always be `1` "within" that loop.
You'd need

```
while ( ($line=fgets($file)) !== false)
```

to change the precedence

Answer (score 2):

Try to put extra brackets:

```
while (( $line=fgets($file) ) !== false) {...}
```